# Recursively sum the nodes of a tree using Postgresql WITH clause

Tags: sql, recursion, postgresql-9.1

(Using Postgresql 9.1)

I have a tree structure in the database and I need to sum the node's values. There are two caveats:

1. Not all nodes have a value.
2. If a parent node has a value, ignore the child values.

While recursing the tree is easy with the powerful recursive WITH clause, it's enforcing these two caveats that is breaking my code. Here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
  id VARCHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO node VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('E');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('F');
INSERT INTO node VALUES ('G');

CREATE TABLE node_value (
  id VARCHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
  value INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO node_value VALUES ('B', 5);
INSERT INTO node_value VALUES ('D', 2);
INSERT INTO node_value VALUES ('E', 0);
INSERT INTO node_value VALUES ('F', 3);
INSERT INTO node_value VALUES ('G', 4);

CREATE TABLE tree (
  parent VARCHAR(1),
  child VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('A', 'B');
INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('B', 'D');
INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('B', 'E');
INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('A', 'C');
INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('C', 'F');
INSERT INTO tree VALUES ('C', 'G');
```

This gives me the following tree (nodes and values):

```
A
|--B(5)
|  |--D(2)
|  |--E(0)
|
|--C
   |--F(3)
   |--G(4)
```

Given the rules above, here are the expected sum values:

```
A = (5 + 3 + 4) = 12
B = 5
D = 2
E = 0
C = (3 + 4) = 7
F = 3
G = 4
```

I have written the following SQL, but I can't integrate the recursive UNION and JOIN logic to enforce rule #1 and #2:

```
WITH recursive treeSum(root, parent, child, total_value) AS (

  SELECT tree.parent root, tree.parent, tree.child, node_value.value total_value
  FROM tree
  LEFT JOIN node_value ON node_value.id = tree.parent

  UNION

  SELECT treeSum.root, tree.parent, tree.child, node_value.value total_value
  FROM tree
  INNER JOIN treeSum ON treeSum.child = tree.parent
  LEFT JOIN node_value ON node_value.id = tree.parent
)

SELECT root, sum(total_value) FROM treeSum WHERE root = 'A' GROUP BY root
```

The query returns 10 for root A, but it should be 12. I know the UNION and/or JOIN logic is what's throwing this off. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, the sum for A is 12, not 14. Given the rules, if a node has a value, grab that value and ignore its children. Because B has a value of 5 we ignore D and E. C has no value, so we grab its children, thus the sum of A = 5(B) + 3(F) + 4(G) = 12. I know it's odd but that's the requirement. Thanks.

EDIT 2: These results will be joined with external datasets so I can't hardcode the root in the WITH clause. For example, I might need something like this:

```
SELECT root, SUM(total_value) FROM treeSUM GROUP BY root WHERE root = 'A'
```

This tree is one of many so that means there's multiple roots, specified by calling code--not within the recursive clause itself. Thanks.

EDIT 3: An example of how this will be used in production is the roots will be specified by another table, so I can't hardcode the root into the recursive clause. There might be many roots from many trees.

```
SELECT id, SUM(COALESCE(value,0)) FROM treeSUM 
INNER JOIN roots_to_select rts ON rts.id = treeSUM.id GROUP BY id
```

SOLUTION (Cleaned up from koriander's answer below)! The following allows roots to be specified by outside sources (either using `roots_to_select` or `WHERE` criteria:

```
WITH recursive roots_to_select AS (
  SELECT 'A'::varchar as id
),

treeSum(root, id, value) AS (

select     node.id as root, node.id, node_value.value
from       node
inner join roots_to_select rts on (node.id = rts.id)
left join  node_value          on (node.id = node_value.id)

union

select     treeSum.root, node.id, node_value.value 
from       treeSum
inner join tree       on (treeSum.id = tree.parent)
inner join node       on (tree.child = node.id)
left join  node_value on (node.id    = node_value.id)
where      treeSum.value is null
)

select   root, sum(coalesce(value, 0))
from     treeSum
group by root
```

OUTPUT: 12

Comment: I usually find it much easier to store a `parent_id` in the same table that contains the "data". In your case the `node` table. This is also better to identify a root in the tree (which is a bit complicated with your setup). But as far as I can tell, the sum for `A` will be 5+2+3+4 (`B` + `D` + `F` + `G`) which is 14

Comment: There's a chance I could modify the schema but it's a legacy system (unfortunately), so I'm hoping to avoid that, even if it requires another join.
EDIT: To clarify, the sum for A is 12, not 14. Given the rules, if a node has a value, ignore its children. Because B has a value of 5 we ignore D and E. C has no value, so we grab its children, thus the sum of A = 5(B) + 3(F) + 4(G) = 12. I know it's odd but that's the requirement.

Comment: Regarding the sum, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2cb44/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9abd6/4):

```
with recursive treeSum(id, value) AS (

select    node.id, node_value.value
from      node
left join node_value on (node.id = node_value.id)
where     node.id = 'A'

union

select     node.id, node_value.value 
from       treeSum
inner join tree       on (treeSum.id = tree.parent)
inner join node       on (tree.child = node.id)
left join  node_value on (node.id = node_value.id)
where      treeSum.value is null
)

select sum(coalesce(value, 0)) from treeSum
```

Edit 1: to combine the result with other table, you can do:

```
select id, (select sum(coalesce(value, 0)) from treeSum) as nodesum
from   node
inner join some_table on (...)
where  node.id = 'A'
```

Edit 2: to support multiple roots based on your Edit 3, you can do (untested):

```
with recursive treeSum(root, id, value) AS (

select     node.id as root, node.id, node_value.value
from       node
inner join roots_to_select rts on (node.id = rts.id)
left join  node_value          on (node.id = node_value.id)

union

select     treeSum.root, node.id, node_value.value 
from       treeSum
inner join tree       on (treeSum.id = tree.parent)
inner join node       on (tree.child = node.id)
left join  node_value on (node.id    = node_value.id)
where      treeSum.value is null
)

select   root, sum(coalesce(value, 0))
from     treeSum
group by root
```

Comment: It's so close to perfect! While the answer is correct, is there a way to re-write it so it can be joined by external data sets? Example:

**SELECT id, sum(coalesce(value,0)) FROM treeSUM GROUP BY id WHERE id = 'A'**

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. The query you just wrote will not give you the sum for the tree, it will return 0. treeSum is like a table, so you can join it for sure. It will depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear; it's an awkward problem to describe. In my example I used one tree with root A, but in the real data set there are _many_ trees with their own roots (but they use the same tables). Let's say there's three trees with roots A, M, and X and I'd like the sum for each one. The query would look like this: `SELECT id, SUM(COALESCE(value,0)) FROM treeSum GROUP BY id WHERE id IN ('A', 'M', 'X')` and that will return three rows.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the root cannot be hardcoded into the recursive clause as it will be specified by another table, like this: `SELECT id, SUM(COALESCE(value,0)) FROM treeSUM INNER JOIN roots_to_select rts ON rts.id = treeSUM.id GROUP BY id`. I hope that helps.

Comment: the simplest would be to turn that query into a prepared statement where the specific root is a parameter. It might be possible to return all the roots summed up but you would need to flag those with an extra attribute in the table. Or have another table with the ids of the roots. And then, ALL records of the CTE must keep track of the root. Please give it a try by yourself and then post another question if you get stuck.

Comment: ok, based on your edit 3, I provided a version for multiple roots.

Comment: You did it! Your Edit #2 works beautifully and solves a long-standing problem. Thank you, koriander.