# calculate sum on each level of a tree with a single CTE with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have three columns
id, parent, value
where parent points at id, describing a tree structure. a leaf node can be identified by "id<0"

how can i calculate a result
"id, sum(value)"

so that sum(value) contains the sum of all values at the current level + all levels below using a recursive CTE?

is it even possible?
what i try to achieve is this:

```
with recursive X
  select * from data where row is a leaf
    union
  select sum(x.value), x.id from x join tree on x.id = tree grouped by  node
```

using the following data set:

```
insert into public.data(id, value, parent_id)
values(1, 8, null),
      (2, 0, null),
      (3, 4, 1),
      (4, 2, 1),
      (5, 1, 4);
```

i need/expect as a result

```
node 5 = value 1
node 4 = value 3 (1+2)
node 3 = value 4
node 2 = value 0
node 1 = value 15 (8+4+3)
```

Comment: Yes, perfectly possible. Try walking the tree first, using a recursive CTE. Then, it becomes easy to process the nodes.

Comment: i can easily traverse the tree, but don't see a way to collect the sums. i can only collect it "along a single branch" or in total. i can't sum it up per node.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it can help you find ID and level of the ID in tree, but I don't fully understand which results must be in the end.

```sql
--create table
create table public.customers(id int primary key,
value decimal,
parent_id int references public.customers(id));

--some data
insert into public.customers(id, value, parent_id)
values(1, 1, null),
(2, 1, null),
(3, 1, 1),
(4, 1, 1),
(5, 1, 4);

--id and level in tree
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, value, parent_id, value sum_value
   FROM   public.customers
   UNION
   SELECT p.id, p.value, p.parent_id, (c.sum_value + p.value) sum_value
   FROM   public.customers p 
   JOIN cte c on p.id= c.parent_id
)
SELECT  id, count(1) level
FROM   cte
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: using the following data set:
~~~
insert into public.customers(id, value, parent_id)
values(1, 8, null),
      (2, 0, null),
      (3, 4, 1),
      (4, 2, 1),
      (5, 1, 4);
~~~
i expect as a result
~~~
node 5 = value 1,
node 4 = value 3 (1+2),
node 3 = value 4,
node 2 = value 0,
node 1 = value 15 (8+4+3)
~~~

Comment: @HamsterofDeath, you need to write Breadth First Search Algorithm to compute the sum of a binary tree (Procedure in this case is an easy way than CTE).  I have found similar question which help you [Recursively sum the nodes of a tree using Postgresql WITH clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274408/recursively-sum-the-nodes-of-a-tree-using-postgresql-with-clause)

Comment: i know i can do this as a function/procedure. but i got challenged to do this with a "simple CTE" and couldn't find a solution. the link shows how to sum everything up for the root node. this, i already solved, it's a simple sum after CTE-ing all the nodes